# How to restrict user from accessing some actions, and show login popup

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

How to restrict user from accessing some actions, and show login popup 
and after successful login show user same action page rather than his profile page.
plz need help friends.

Comment: Please, provide more details. Tell us what you have already written and what exactly is your problem.

Comment: i have one login_rquired method in application controller which check for user session.and in befor_filter i have specified this method in private messages controller,when user click on some other user profile then i have to show login pop-up and when user login he should land on other user profile page rather than his profile page.

Comment: @sonalkumar Store source/referrer url in session in login_required before_filter when the login form should be displayed. In the login action check this session key. If session key with source url is set, redirect the user to that url.

Comment: Thnx Hck.i think this should work for me.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use permissions checking gems, like CanCan. You'll be able to specify permissions checking for each action and to specify global permissions for each user role etc.

Read more here: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

Comment: +1 It looks like you were able to answer in a few words a question I found hardly answerable ;-)

Comment: @sonalkumar: then you definitely should say it in your question. Otherwise you may be accused of wasting the energy of ones who try to find solutions you know to be unacceptable.

Comment: @Arsen7 i will take care of that.from next time.thnx.